# How to understand "State of the application should be stored in a file"?

Tags: java, state

I have been learning Java on my own for a while, and I finally received a recruitment task, where I'm supposed to create a program in which user can order a pizza, or a few pizzas, with option to customize its ingredients. Now, I believe I understand all but one requirement, that is "State of the application should be stored in a file". I'm not sure how to approach this, so far I came up with generating a .txt file after each order is submitted, containing:

- Name of the user that made the order (also a requirement listed in the task);
- List of pizzas, each with its own list of ingredients (one of the requirements is to be able to add/remove ingredients from pizzas).

And files would be named something along the lines "Pizza order" + user name + HH:MM of file creation.

I would ask for clarifications, but I'm worried that this may be something trivial, and subsequently disqualify me from the recruitment process.

Comment: In this case "state" is clearly the list of orders with all details. I.e. if I launch the program and enter an order, exist it and relaunch it, then I should be able to see the order I entered before. Note that the requirement says "a file", indicating that you should have a single file for everything you want to store.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. Thanks